# The Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem: Example.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

The following question is from Real Analysis by Royden (4th Edition). More precisely, it is problem 36 of chapter 4. Further, the problem follows right after the section over The Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, hence, that is what should be used. Below is the problem followed by my attempted solution which I have a question about.

---

**Problem:**

Let $f$ be a real-valued function of two variables $\left(x,y\right)$ that is defined on the following unit square
$Q:=\{\left(x,y\right): 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1\}$ and is a measurable function of $x$ for each fixed value of
$y$. For each $\left(x,y\right)\in Q$ let the partial derivative a $\partial f/\partial y$ exist. Suppose there is a function $g$ that is integrable over $[0,1]$ and such that,

$$\left\vert\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x,y\right)\right\vert \leq g(x) \text{ for all } \left(x,y\right)\in Q.\tag{*}$$

Prove that

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left[\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx\right] = \int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx, \text{ for all } y\in[0,1].$$

---

(My) *Proof:*

Fix $y\in[0,1]$ and consider the sequence of functions $f_n\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by,

$$f_n(x):=\frac{f(x,y+1/n) - f(x,y)}{1/n}.$$

Then, $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions ($f$ is a measurable function of $x$ for each fixed value of $y$) dominated by $g(x)$ that converge pointwise almost everywhere to $\partial f/\partial y$ on $[0,1]$ (for each $(x,y)\in Q$ the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial y$ exists). Therefore, by The Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n=\int_0^1f$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{f(x,y+1/n) - f(x,y)}{1/n}dx = 
\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx.\tag{1}$$

Notice,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{f(x,y+1/n) - f(x,y)}{1/n}dx = 
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_0^1f(x,y+h)dx-\int_0^1f(x,y)dx}{h}= 
\frac{d}{dy}\left[\int_0^1f(x,y)dx\right].\tag{2}$$

Thus, combining (1) and (2),

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left[\int_0^1f(x,y)dx\right] = \int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)dx,$$

which was to be shown.

---

My main concern with my proof is that, I am not sure how the sequence $\{f_n\}$ are dominated by $g(x)$. I know by (*) that the limit of the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is bounded by $g(x)$. Also, if there are any mistakes in the proof, please let me know!

**Edit:**

Does the boundedness of the $\{f_n\}$ come from the fact that every convergent sequence is a bounded sequence?

Comment: to avoid confusing, you shouldn't write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n=\int_0^1f$ as $f$ is the initial function.

Comment: Is $f_n$ only "almost everywhere" converging? If so, can someone explain why?

Comment: @Rem Let fixed $y$. For every $x$, we have $\lim_n f_n(x)=\partial_y f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Leon So we make no assumption that it is only "almost everywhere" pointwise convergent, right? I understand that we don't need more than that for the proof though.

Comment: Yes, i think so.

Comment: @Rem: It converges pointwise $\implies$ it converges pointwise almost everywhere. As you said, we do not need more than pointwise almost everywhere for the proof, and so I decided to write "pointwise  almost everywhere" to emphasis the conditions of the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I was not missing a reason why we would not have pointwise convergence. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $y \in [0,1]$ and any sequence $y_n \in [0,1]$ such that $y_n \to y$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi_{x,n}$ between $y$ and $y_n$ such that

$$|f_n(x)| = \left|\frac{f(x,y_n) - f(x,y)}{y_n - y} \right| = \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,\xi_{x,n})\right| \leqslant g(x)$$

We have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x,y_n) - f(x,y)}{y_n - y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y),$$

and by the dominated convergence theorem

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{f(x,y_n) - f(x,y)}{y_n - y}\, dx = \int_0^1\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x,y_n) - f(x,y)}{y_n - y}\, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \, dx$$

Comment: This makes sense, but is it wrong to say "the boundedness of the $\{f_n\}$ come from the fact that every convergent sequence is a bounded sequence"?

Comment: The principle you seem to be invoking is that a sequence $(a_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that is convergent is bounded -- meaning that there exists $B>0$ such that $|a_n| \leqslant B$ for all $n$.  Here we can say that convergence of $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ implies that $f_n(x)$ is bounded in the pointwise sense.

Comment: ... but what you really have is $f_n(x,y)$ depending on both variables.  So this all gets taken care of nicely with MVT.

Comment: So, if we can say that the convergence of $f_n \to f$ implies that $f_n(x)$ is bounded in the pointwise sense, why does this not work to conclude The Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem? But yes, I ultimately agree the MVT works very well here.

Comment: If all I know is that $f_n(x,y)$ converges pointwise with respect to $x,y$ as $n \to \infty$, then I can conclude  that there exists $B(x,y)>0$ such that $|f_n(x,y)| \leqslant B(x,y)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x,y$ fixed.  I can't say more about $B$ at this point -- for example, that there is a uniform bound for all $y$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I was looking over this, and was wondering how to we know that $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[y,y+1/n]$ and differentiable on $(y,y+1/n)$ (the conditions in order to apply the MVT)? I know that $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$.

Comment: With $y \in [0,1]$ take any sequence  $y_n \in [0,1]$ such that $y_n \to 0$ and define $f_n(x) = \frac{f(x,y_n) - f(x,y)}{y_n - y}$ and apply the LDCT as you did.  We can be sure that $f$ is differentiable with respect to $y$ at any point between $y$ and $y_n$ and use the MVT.

Comment: @D.Math: I expanded the answer.  It should be clear now why the conditions of MVT  hold as long as the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ exists for $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0,1]$.  And typo in comment above $y_n \to 0$ should be $y_n \to y$.

Comment: It is very clear now, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to prove that $f_n$ is bounded by $g$ is
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)| = & \bigg \vert \frac{ f(x, y+1/n)-f(x,y)}{1/n}\bigg \vert\\
         = & \bigg \vert \frac{ \int_y^{y+1/n} \partial_y f(x,y) dy }{1/n}\bigg \vert\\
         \leq & \frac{ \int_y^{y+1/n} |\partial_y f(x,y)| dy }{1/n}\\
         \leq & g(x).
\end{align}

Comment: This is a cool way, thanks for presenting. The last inequality is bugging me though. Mind explaining it? I know that $|\partial_{y}f(x,y)| \leq g(x)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! the last one is because $\int_y^{y+1/n} dy=(y+1/n)-y=1/n$.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. The $g(x)$ is not a function of $y$.